# Display preconfigured price for bundle products on product listing page in magento2.x

Tags: magento-2.3

In magento2 by default price range (from and to price) is displaying on product listing page for group products. 
On product detail page when we click on "Customize and Add to Cart" button then under customisation section preconfigured bundle product price is displayed. This bundle price is based on the selected default option's price in admin.

We do not want to display the price range on product listing page . We only want to display the preconfigured price on listing page same as it displayed on product detail page .

How can we display the preconfigured price on listing page for grouped products like preconfigured price displayed on product detail page ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a frontend observer:
app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
        <observer name="catalog_category_set_bundle_product_price"    instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Product\SetBundleProductPriceCollection"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer:
app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Product/SetBundleProductPriceCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Bundle\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\Collector\BundlePrice;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

/**
 * Class SetBundleProductPriceCollection
 */
class SetBundleProductPriceCollection implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Identifier of PLP Controller action
     */
    const PLP_MODULE_CONTROLLER_ACTION = 'catalog_category_view_catalog';

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @param Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Execute
     *
     * @param Observer $observer Observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $moduleName = $this->request->getModuleName();
        $controller = $this->request->getControllerName();
        $action     = $this->request->getActionName();
        $route      = $this->request->getRouteName();

        $routerAction = $moduleName.'_'.$controller.'_'.$action.'_'.$route;
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if ($routerAction == self::PLP_MODULE_CONTROLLER_ACTION) {
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                if ($product->getTypeId() === BundlePrice::PRODUCT_TYPE) {
                    $bundleObj = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
                    $product->setPrice($bundleObj->getMinimalPrice()->getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```